# Women or the women? (Use of the definite artice with plural nouns)

Tags: definite-article

“**The** women of Leningrad came to replace their husbands who had gone to the front.”

“**The** women in ancient Rome used cosmetics.”

**How would the meaning of these senesces change if they read:**

“Women of Leningrad came to replace their husbands who had gone to the front.”

“Women in ancient Rome used cosmetics.”

Comment: The A of B is standard. Those specific ones.

Comment: So, there is a rule that an “of phrase” should always be preceded by the definite article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In formal writing, one would probably write:

The women of Leningrad, those specific women at the time. [**in comparison, to, say, the men, soldiers or children of the same city]. If you are presenting a picture of a place with all sorts of parts and details, I would use: The A of B.**

Otherwise: Women of Leningrad have red hair. Women in Ancient Rome used cosmetics. Both fine.

The rule is more stylistic, not grammatical per se.

General statements: **Women in the ancient world were generally good cooks. But the women of Athens were not.** You have to "feel" it.